# Failure when creating service fabric cluster with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to create a service fabric cluster with a powershell script.  Here's the script:

```bsh
Param(
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="Azure user name")]
    [String]$azUserName,
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="Azure password")]
    [String]$azPassword,
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="What is the resource group name?")]
    [String]$ResourceGroupName="sfLinuxClusterRg",
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="What is the key vault group name?")]
    [String]$KeyVaultResourceGroupName="KeyVaultRg",
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="Where is the azure location?")]
    [String]$Location="uksouth",
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="what is the key vault group?")]
    [String]$VaultGroupName="linuxclusterkeyvaultgroup",
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="Where is the certificate stored locally?")]
    [String]$CertFileName="certificate.pfx",
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="What is the subscription id?")]
    [String]$SubscriptionId,
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="What is the tenant id?")]
    [String]$TenantId
)

Function DecryptSecureString([SecureString] $secureText){
    return [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secureText))    
}

Function CreateKeyVaultCert(){

    try{
        Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId `
                            -TenantId $TenantId

        # Create a Resource Group to hold your Key Vault(s)
        # Note this should be separate from your other resources so you can delete those other resource groups without impacting your registered certs
        New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $KeyVaultResourceGroupName -Location uksouth  -Force 

        # Create a Key Vault to hold your secrets
        New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $KeyVaultResourceGroupName `
            -Location uksouth -EnabledForDeployment `
            -EnabledForDiskEncryption -EnabledForTemplateDeployment 

        # Have Key Vault create the certificate with a simple policy
        $policy = New-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy `
            -SubjectName "CN=cluster123.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com" `
            -IssuerName Self -ValidityInMonths 12 

        Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name cert1 -CertificatePolicy $policy 

        Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -EnabledForDeployment

        Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -EmailAddress $azUserName -PermissionsToSecrets Get
    }
    catch{
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        exit
    }  
}

$azPassword = $azPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
Import-AzureRmContext -Path "C:\stuff\AzureProfile.json"

$Date = Get-Date
$VaultName="VaultLearn" + $Date.ToString("hhmmss")

# sign in to your Azure account and select your subscription
$certName = "CN=cluster123.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com"
$clustersize=5 
$clustername = "cluster123" + $Date.ToString("hhmmss")
$adminuser="admin" 
$vmsku = "Standard_D2_v2"
$os = "UbuntuServer1604"

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

CreateKeyVaultCert

New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster -Name $clustername `
                                -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                -Location uksouth `
                                -ClusterSize $clustersize `
                                -VmUserName $adminuser -VmPassword $azPassword `
                                -CertificateSubjectName $certName `
                                -CertificatePassword $azPassword `
                                -VmSku $vmsku `
                                -CertificateOutputFolder 'C:\stuff' `
                                -OS $os `
                                -KeyVaultName $VaultName

Write-Host "Created service fabric cluster in resource group $ResourceGroupName"

#Add-AzureRmAccount
# $path = "C:\stuff\AzureProfile.json"
# Save-AzureRmContext -Path $path -Force
```

I keep getting the error:

New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster : The name 'VaultLearn090903' is already in use.

This is really weird, because I'm pretty sure yesterday this script at least attempted to create the cluster, although I was getting another error about Ubuntu image not being found.  What could be causing this error?

By the way, in order to run this script, I have previously run this code:

```bsh
Add-AzureRmAccount
$path = "C:\stuff\AzureProfile.json"
Save-AzureRmContext -Path $path -Force
```

which has cached my azure credentials locally.

I have specifically added two statements into the script to add a policy for access to the keyvault:

```bsh
            Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -EnabledForDeployment
            Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -EmailAddress $azUserName -PermissionsToSecrets Get
```

I know this is probably overkill, but I'm trying to get rid of this problem.

The other weird thing is I have tried the [Azure Sample Github repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-cluster-templates/tree/master/5-VM-Ubuntu-1-NodeTypes-Secure)

I'm at a loss for how I can continue with service fabric.

Comment: What happens if you run `Get-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster` (i.e. to check if a service cluster genuinely does already exist)?  Presumably it did work when you ran it yesterday, so created the service cluster; hence when you're trying to create it today you're getting an error stating that it already exists.

Comment: Hi John, thx for your response. I should say that just before I submit the command,  I do try and make sure I,ve deleted all resource groups in all subscriptions I have. Also, the name in the error is always date stamped with the same hours minutes and seconds on my computer. Seems key vault has just  been created which is weird (being somehow submitted twice?)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

I managed to get something different working by going to the azure portal, creating a service fabric cluster and downloading the ARM template (which includes some powershell scripts).

thanks